# ValueError: too many dimensions 'str' python in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, lstm, torch, valueerror

I keep getting the error:

ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'

I attach my colab notebook to have a look at it. Have not found anything online yet that helps me solve the problem.

link:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ikol2D8mmiIPKhNHbcFlTfVpuU_Gf9BZ?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I had once got the same error and it was due to passing of a string to **torch.tensor()** while it can't handle string data . So' just check the data you are passing to **torch.tensor()** and convert it to integers if it is string

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error as well in my Jupyter notebook.  I can reproduce it with the following simple code:

```
Input:
tensor(['a'])

Output: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-3bdb0dbfafc2> in <module>
----> 1 tensor(['a'])
...(stacktrace)...

ValueError: too many dimensions 'str'
```

Apparently PyTorch tensors are different from Numpy arrays in that [they don't work with strings](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html), only integers, floats, and booleans.

The above error indicates that there are too many strings passed to the tensor (i.e. even one string is too many).  When I change the code to the following, it works fine:

```
Input:
tensor([1])

Output: 
tensor([1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your notebook yet, but I just solved mine with the same error. Just double check if all training datasets and labels are converted to numeric values or tensors. If you have multiple columns in your dataframe, remove the one that does not need to feed into the training loop.